# NxN grid with countries and each country has some population

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, grid

I have to simulate a contagious disease spread where the world is of NxN countries. Initially there are going to be P people in the world and then we have to assign the people uniformly at random to each country.

The problem I am having is that how do I go about assigning a number of people to each country?

If I have an array such as

```
String[][] world = new String[2][2];
```

I have 4 countries now and I can show them as a grid using for loops.

Now world[0][0] which is a country should point to a list which has people in it.

I tried list within a list

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<human>> world2 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<human>>();
ArrayList<human> country1 = new ArrayList<human>();


for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    human h = new human();
    country1.add(i,h);
}

world2.add(country1);

ArrayList<human> country2 = new ArrayList<human>();
human h = new human();
country2.add(h);
world2.add(country2);

for (int i=0; i<world2.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(world2.get(i));
}
```

But how do i print it in a grid format ?

**EDIT1:**

```
 String[][] world = new String[2][2];
  for (int row = 0; row < world.length; row++) {
            System.out.print("|");
           for (int col = 0; col < world.length; col++) {
                System.out.print(world[row][col] + "| ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
|null| null| 
|null| null|
```

Comment: Have you defined a `toString` method on `Human` and then used for loops as described above with your matrix of `String`?

Comment: Yes I have a toString in human class and currently it returns "Human". The list within a list method is good but the problem I am facing with that is how do I print that in a gird format ?

Comment: Can you provide your expected output that you referenced in your `String` matrix example? Also the code you used in that case will be helpful.

Comment: @NedRockson I provided the for loop which prints the grid format for the world array and I want to do this same for the arraylist because this solution is not suitable as I want to show a number of people at world[0][0]

Comment: you need to initialize each population per country and that's why they are null

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz Thats not the question. I know why they are null. I want to keep a number of people at lets say [0][0]. It should show lets say "human" ten times.

Comment: so you want a 3D arraylist? that's what you'll need if you have multiple humans at [0][0]

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz Yes I am asking for a solution for such a problem. If you could show with an example and I think it would solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will loop through a 3D arraylist of Integers and print the contents of all the Integer per [row][col] of the world grid. All you have to do is supplement your Human object into wherever I have Integer.

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>> create3D()
{
    ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>> world = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>>();
    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
    {
        world.add(new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>());
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) 
        {
            world.get(row).add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
            Random rand = new Random();
            int randomNum = rand.nextInt((20 - 1) + 1) + 1;
            for(int humanNumber = 0; humanNumber < randomNum; humanNumber++)
                world.get(row).get(col).add(humanNumber);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    return world;
}

public void printHumanGrid(ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>> world)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < world.size(); row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < world.get(row).size(); col++) 
        {
            System.out.print("|");
            for(int humanNumber = 0; humanNumber < world.get(row).get(col).size(); humanNumber++)
                System.out.print(world.get(row).get(col).get(humanNumber) + ",");

            System.out.print("|");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

So I ahve two functions, one to fill a 3D arraylist and the other to print it out. Running the following

```
printHumanGrid(create3D());
```

Outputs:

```
|0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,||0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,||0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,|
|0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,||0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,||0,1,2,3,|
|0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,||0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,||0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,|
```

Each line is a row in the grid. You can now add onto it, perhaps adding functionality to format it and whatnot. Good luck!